# JUnit best practise - testing methods, where the result cannot be verified with public methods

Tags: java, junit4, private, private-members

I am writing a Socket Application in Java, where a server is taking messages from an eventsource and sending notifications to connected users, depending on the eventtype.

Now I am about to write some JUnit tests for the Server...
JUnit (in eclipse automatically suggests) to implement tests for all public methods and I see the necessity for it. The server class has a public method bufferEvent..., but then the events are handled in private methods and there is not even a method, which returns the number of buffered messages.

So the Server doesn't have public methods to verify the result.

I think the problem can be generalized: 
How can I test public methods, where the result cannot be verified with public methods( no getter etc.)

I want to avoid writing additional methods just for testing. Is there a workaround, or best practise to test those things?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably reflection could help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141626/changing-private-methods-to-protected-for-testing

Comment: can you provide your code? We have TDD coaches in our company and they explained us some tricks, but the vary based on the source code. Sometimes you don't have to test results of method, but just to check if some calls are properly done. Sometimes you have design flaw and the private method should actually reside in another class and be public and therefore testable.

Comment: Hey guys, this is a test exercise for an application, so I am not supposed to expose it, it's also way to much at the moment, to ask someonw look over it. But thanks alot for the offer...

Comment: Reflection work perfect!!! Thank you so much! That's more lines, but some test seem to work fine, so I can leave all the visibilites as they are. so coool

Answer (score 2):

You should make a constructor that allows you to insert mocks or spies for the collaborators.

For example, you server would have a constructor `Server(List<Buffer> buffer)`. Only used for testing. Then you can add the buffer in the unit test, and assert that modifications are made to that buffer.

List is easy enough to replace with a object you create in the test. If you want more advanced stuff, have a look at a mocking framework like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

For example you create a mock for a Socket. You'd get `Socket = mock(Socket.class`. You insert in in the constructor `Server(List<Buffer> buffer, Socket socket)`. Then after you have called whatever function you want to test, you can verify behavior using for example `verify(socket).send("yourMessage")` to see if the server used the method `send` with parameters "yourMessage".

For example [this `Plugins` class](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/blob/2063644fe892c5ac4e6d1514b9ed6ed743eec11d/core/src/main/java/com/crawljax/core/plugin/Plugins.java) requires some plugins in it's constructor. To test its the mocks are created, inserted and then verified [in this test class](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/blob/2063644fe892c5ac4e6d1514b9ed6ed743eec11d/core/src/test/java/com/crawljax/core/plugin/PluginsTest.java) like this: `verify(proxyServerPlugin).proxyServer(config);`.

See the [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) for more examples.

Comment: Hi Alex, 
thanks using mocks sounds good. I would have to create a constructor to add some mock objects tho just for testing, but by doing so, I could at least, test multiple functions, by adding all necessary mocks to the construtcor

Comment: To be sure, you can add the `@VisibleForTesting` annotation by Google Guice to tell other developers the constructor is only there for testing. You of course have to make the constructor package protected as well to make sure no one abuses it.

Comment: that sound also nice. Unfortunately I am supposed to use no 3rd party libraries, since it is a application test exersice...

Answer (score 1):

You could check the negative test case. There is no return from the service but maybe there is an exception which is thrown by the service:

```
@Test
public void testServerService(){
try{
   myServer.service();
   Assert.assertTrue(true);
}catch(Exception ex){
   Assert.fail("anything goes wrong");
}
}
```

Otherwise in such cases I write something like this:

```
@Test
public void testServerService(){
   myServer.service();
   Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

so I have at least on assertion to check if the process runs without problems.

btw I think you are right. writing new functionality just to verify Junit testcases is very bad practice.

Comment: `Assert.assertTrue(true)` is a redundant statement. The test will finish successfully without it.

If you expect and exception, use `@Test(expected=YourException.class)` or if you don't expect it throw the exception. JUnit will print the failure for you.

Comment: Hi Stefan,thanks for pointing out that I should avoid additional functions. It is a test exercise for an application. And the code should be following best practise... :) So good that I didn't start doing that

Answer (score 0):

What do think about adding a Logger, with it's own Level TEST , loggin important values at the end of the methods and having a stream to A testclass.

Comment: okay that wasn't such a good idea. Reflections work very well!