# How to unit test a private method using Minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I wanted to test a private method but I came across an answer that states simply **YOU DONT!**

How can I refactor this code so that I can test it?

In my controller, I have a private method

```
 def move_employees
    return unless params[:store_id].present?
    store = scope.find(params[:store_id])
    store.employments << @store.employments
    store.save!
 end
```

This method is called inside the destroy action such that when I want to delete a store that has employees, I can move them over to an existing store picked from an drop down menu

```
def destroy
    @store = scope.find(params[:id])
    authorize([:manage, :settings, @store])
    if @store.destroy
        move_employees
...
```

I am thinking of moving the method to the model, but I am not sure if that is the best approach, and also, I don't know how I would then test it.

What is the best practice in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Private methods should be tested implicitly through the "public interface". If the method needs individual testing, consider to make it `protected`  and expose it in a dedicated `TestModelImplementation` class...

Comment: This is a common "issue" with OOP languages. A similar discussion can be found for Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141626/changing-private-methods-to-protected-for-testing). The results and thoughts can be applied here, too.

Comment: Hi Cpt, thanks, does that mean I can leave it in the Controller? just have it protected? 

Also, can I still test the protected method in the controller_spec?

Comment: Usually - in terms of [fat model, skinny controller](https://dev.to/kputra/rails-skinny-controller-skinny-model-5f2k) I like my destroy methods in the model. My rational is: It interacts directly on the model itself. But that is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Philosophically, you shouldn't, as private methods are expected to be tested in the context of the public code. For example, if `move_employees` must be called as part of `destroy`, test the end state, not the mechanism to get there. That is, assert that after deletion the employees are correctly moved.

Practically you *can* test directly if you're prepared to bust out `send`. This more direct method of testing can be useful for particularly complex implementations, but in those cases you should probably separate your concerns and have some other tool that facilitates that operation which does have a public interface.

Comment: Food for thought. Thanks Tadman. Let me see how I can implement your suggestions.

Comment: The challenge I had with the implementation is I already have Cypress integration tests that assert if store A displays 5 employees and store B displays 0 employees, then after clicking on the move employees button then deleting store A, store B will display 5 employees. 

But after writing that test, I wondered whether I needed to add a minitest for that method and if it would be redundant.

Comment: Sometimes redundant tests help validate things from a different angle, and can prove useful. Other times they just fossilize a bad design. It's only obvious in hindsight, so I wouldn't worry.

Comment: I was able to refactor the method into the model, but speaking of bad design. I may have still not designed the code well because the test is not straight forward. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74630513/how-to-test-a-before-destroy-callback-minitest