# How to test a before_destroy callback minitest

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Yesterday I asked a question about [How to unit test a private method using Minitest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617131/how-to-unit-test-a-private-method-using-minitest/74618984#74618984)

I was told you should never be testing private methods.

So I took the logic out of the controller and into the model which now looks like this

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :selected_store_id
  
  before_destroy :move_employees_to_selected_store
  
  scope :by_name, -> { order(name: :asc) }

  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :employments

  validates_presence_of :name

  def move_employees_to_selected_store
    return unless selected_store_id.present?
    store = organization.store.find(selected_store_id)
    employments.update_all(store_id: store.id)
  end
end
```

And that works! **(The selected_store_id is updated in the view)**

But I have run into an problem because I dont see how I can test that method since I cant pass in the `selected_store_id`.

I was about to try the following but that assertion will not be true!

```
 def test_employments_are_moved_to_selected_store_when_store_is_removed
    u = UserFactory.create
    o = OrganizationFactory.create
    s1 = o.store.create(name: "Test")
    s2 = o.store.create(name: "Test 2")
    s1.employments.create(user: u)
    s1.destroy
    assert_equal s2.employments.count, 1
  end
```

How can I refactor either my test or my callback to pass in the store id?

Comment: You have created an `attr_accessor`, so why can't you pass in the `selected_store_id` using this? i.e. `s1.selected_store_id = s2.id`

Comment: I have tried that, but 
```s1.selected_store_id = s2.id
   s1.destroy
    assert_equal Employment.where(store_id: v2.id).count, 1
```

Does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your controller knows about picking a selected store.
and knows it needs to do this before destroying.

Having the controller actually transfer the employees has less hidden logic and is easier to test.

```rb
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  scope :by_name, -> { order(name: :asc) }

  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :employments

  validates_presence_of :name

  def transfer_employees(new_store)
    employments.update_all(store_id: new_store.id)
  end
end

class StoreController
  def destroy # before (I'm guessing)
    @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
    @store.selected_store_id = params[:selected_store_id]
    @store.destroy
  end

  def destroy # after
    @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
    @new_store = Store.find(params[:selected_store_id])
    @store.transfer_employees(@new_store)
    @store.destroy
  end
end

class StoreTest
 def test_employments_are_transferred
    u = UserFactory.create
    o = OrganizationFactory.create
    s1 = o.stores.create(name: "Test")
    s2 = o.stores.create(name: "Test 2")
    s1.employments.create(user: u)
    s1.transfer_employees(s2)
    assert_equal s2.employments.count, 1
  end
end
```

If you notice that the store destroy starts to get mailing lists and other logic, move it to a service/transaction object.

```rb
class StoreController
  def destroy
    @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
    @new_store = Store.find(params[:selected_store_id])
    DestroyStore.new.destroy_store(@store, @new_store)
  end
end

class DestroyStoreService
  def destroy_store(store1, store2)
    store1.transfer_employees(store2)
    store1.destroy
  end
end
```

Not optimal, but you could move the service layer into the object, but I tend to like business logic separate from the data layer where possible.

```rb
class Store
  def destroy_and_transfter(new_store)
    transfer_employees(new_store)
    destroy
  end
end
```

Good luck